# How to check password for number of lowercase letters entered?

Tags: java, loops, validation, passwords

I am using the below script to check my passwords for length, number of uppercase letters and number of digits.

Is there a way to make it also check for the number of lowercase letters? I tried to revamp my code a few times but each time I do it kicks out the other two checks. Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.*;
public class ValidatePassword {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String inputPassword;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean success=false;
    while(!success){

    System.out.print("Password: ");
    inputPassword = input.next();
    System.out.println(PassCheck(inputPassword));
    if(PassCheck(inputPassword).equals("Valid Password")) success = true; 
    System.out.println("");

    } 
  }

  public static String PassCheck(String Password) {
    String result = "Valid Password";
    int length = 0;
    int numCount = 0;
    int capCount = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < Password.length(); x++) {
      if ((Password.charAt(x) >= 47 && Password.charAt(x) <= 58) || (Password.charAt(x) >= 64 && Password.charAt(x) <= 91) ||
        (Password.charAt(x) >= 97 && Password.charAt(x) <= 122)) {
      } else {
        result = "Password Contains Invalid Character!";
      }
      if ((Password.charAt(x) > 47 && Password.charAt(x) < 58)) {
        numCount++;
      }
      if ((Password.charAt(x) > 64 && Password.charAt(x) < 91)) {
        capCount++;
      }
      
      length = (x + 1);
    }
    if (numCount < 2) {
      result = "digits";
    }
    if (capCount < 2) {
      result = "uppercase letters";
    }
    if (capCount < 2) {
      result = "uppercase letters";
    }
    if (numCount < 2 && capCount < 2) 
    {
      result = "uppercase letters digits";
    }

    if (length < 2) {
      result = "Password is Too Short!";
    }
    return (result);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried copying the three lines that check whether to increment `capCount`, using a new variable such as `lowercaseCount`?

Comment: @VGR I did. I used the variable lowCapCount but when I add the three new lines it kicks out the validation of the numCount and capCount variables out. Do you have any other suggestions? Thanks again in advance!

Comment: In your code there is no checking of lowercase letters separately.

Comment: @imraklr I know there isn't a separate check for the lowercase letters yet. Each time I try to add a lowCapCount variable it quits checking for the number of uppercase letters and number of letters and only checks for the lowercase letters after that. I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong in my code? I'm sorry if the way I wrote my question wasn't clear, I'm new to Java and relatively new to Stackoverflow and am just seeking some professional help for this project. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @Kay Can you please include checking of lower case letter condition in your code? I find no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking each character one by one is a tedious task and will increase your logical error. You can use Regular Expressions for this. Your modified 'PassCheck' method:-

```
public static String PassCheck(String Password) {
    int length = Password.length();
    if(length<2)
        return "Password is Too Short!";
    String regex = "^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]+$";
    boolean d = Password.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "").length()<2;
    boolean u = Password.replaceAll("[^A-Z]", "").length()<2;
    boolean l = Password.replaceAll("[^a-z]", "").length()<2;
    if(d && u)
        return "digits uppercase";
    else if(l&&u)
        return "lowercase uppercase";
    else if(l&&d)
        return "lowercase digits";
    else if(d)
        return "digits";
    else if(u)
        return "uppercase";
    else if(l)
        return "lowercase";
    else if(!(Password.matches(regex)))
        return "Password contains Invalid Character!";
    return "Valid Password";
}
```